# How can I get angular to process a string value to read it as a dictionary call?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am attempting to use angular material table component to build a table that can display user selected list of columns for nested JSON objects, and running into issues with deeper than 1 level portions of the dictionary.

```
<div *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
    <ng-container *ngIf="check(column)" [matColumnDef]="column">
        <th mat-header-cell cdkDrag *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 200px;">
            {{column}}
        </th>
        <td class="concat" nz-tooltip [nzTooltipTitle]="elementColumnTemplate" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <!-- This will only work for single depth terms... how to deal with multi depth elements? .. -->
            {{ element[column] }}
            {{ dictParser(element, column) }}
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #elementColumnTemplate>
        {{ dictParser(element, column) }}
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

Here is the code for typescript/javascript portion of the code, the parsing function:

```
dictParser(element, cols)
{
    var str = `element?.${cols.replaceAll(".", "?.")}`
    return str
}
```

Small explanation on this function: I have a dropdown list of flattened possible fields, something like this:

```
somefield,
some_info.depth_1.devices.causal.category,
some_info.depth_1.devices.causal.names,
some_info.depth_1.fqdns,
some_info.depth_1.ips,
some_info.depth_1.location.city,
etc... etc...
```

If the user would like, they can append such a column to the table. And in the 'td' portion of the HTML code, I try to render the column ... element?.field?.field?.field

The typescript function doesnt currently use the element object to do anything, but if I need to traverse the dict on typescript side, I will do that next.

The return statement in the typescript function (which is called in the 'th' part of the html code.) currently gives something like:

```
element?.custom_info?.enrichment?.deviceNames
```

My hope was that the

```
{{ function call ... }} <-
```

portion of the HTML will force the string to render as the value of the dictionary 'element' but all it does is display that string. Is there a way to add an additional level of 'processing' the string text as me trying to fetch the value of dictionary?

Comment: You should probably just try to make it so the return value of the string is the value you want to show to the user. How do you get the flatten keys ? Would using a library such as `flat` help here ? If you can flatten `element`, you could access the attribute by doing `flatten(element)[cols]`

Comment: Big brain hours! Flattening the element object seems to do the trick!